# Representing multiple asynchronous threads in UML Interaction diagram

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, uml, sequence-diagram

I am having a flow which at a very high level looks like below:-

1. Multiple subscriber threads are subscribed to a queue
2. Whenever there is a message in queue one subscriber thread receives it
3. A call is made to a database table `C`.
4. The message is transformed by using the value returned from table `C` and written to a database table `A`
5. An acknowledgement is sent to the queue to delete the message from queue
6. A background thread keeps polling the database table `A` at a specified interval
7. The background thread reads the messages those are present in table `A`
8. The messages are transformed by calling method `transform()`.
9. The transformed messages are written to table `B`.
10. The original message is deleted from table `A`.

I have tried to represent the above flow via the following UML Sequence Diagram:-

[image]

Can someone let me know how can I update the above diagram to add the following information:-

1. How can I represent multiple subscriber threads listening asynchronously to the queue?
2. How to represent the database calls and the different table?
3. How to represent the background polling that is happening at a specified interval (let's say once in 10 second) ?

Are there any alternative to UML Sequence diagram to communicate the flow clearly?

Comment: Could you please draw the diagram for a single subscriber? Then we could help you to model the multiple subscribers case. Also, please write your scenario in complete English sentences, because I don't quite get it.

Comment: I have updated the question. The doubt I am having is how to represent the following in UML Sequence Diagram - 1) multiple subscribers, 2) reading messages from queue asynchronously & 3) background polling in specified intervals

Comment: Please make an attempt and draw a single-subscriber to a queue. Once you have that we can give you the right direction for multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't represent multiple subscriber threads listening, because during listening, no messages are exchanged. What you can do, is show a few instances of Subscriber, each making a subscription.
2. You have two options: show each table as a separate lifeline (as you did), or show the database as a single lifeline and let the message specify which table is accessed (I think this is how most designers would do it).
3. You could show a couple of extra getMessages messages getting nothing in return.

Comment: Is there a way I can show polling is happening once in every 10 seconds.